# Retrofit Convert Post to Get request

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

i have post request which i want to convert to get request any way i can do . as of now i know is i have to change all stuff like

```
 @POST("apiname")
Call<ResponseBody> getBasic(@Body DataRequest data);
```

and DataRequest is having say 5 params . now

```
 @GET("apiname")
Call<ResponseBody> getBasic(
        @Query("one") String one,
        @Query("two") String two,
        @Query("three") String three)..;
```

so in this way i have to add number of variables to  @Query but problem is if its 10 then i have to add 10 time . is any other workaround where i can convert POST to GET

any way i can pass POJO model and it converted to get request format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@QueryMap` to pass multiple query params dynamically. So in your case:

```
@GET("apiname")
Call<ResponseBody> getBasic(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

You can then define a method in your pojo to convert it to a `Map<String, String>`

Comment: it is available in java ?

Comment: @andro this is java^^